# Can't mute a NetStream

Tags: apache-flex, flash-media-server

I'm creating a video chat app using Flash Media Server 4 and Flex, using RTMFP for peer-to-peer.

No matter what I try, I cannot mute a user's NetStream. I tried receiveAudio(false) and that does not work.

I tried capturing the stream SoundTransform and setting the volume of that to 0, that does not work.

I tried setting the mx VideoDisplay volume to 0 and that does not work.

I can set the alpha of the VideoDisplay, so its really strange that I cannot set the volume.

BTW, I am not trying to mute the mic of the user who launched the app, that I can do. I'm trying to mute one of the other users stream in the Flex app, that way the app makes it possible to not hear people who are perhaps being offensive.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You should be able to.  Please show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pleas clear that can you able to modify the front End page that capture the Net Stream.

Because you only mute the sound at client side in Flex Video/ Cam capturing.

So try this one at client side if you have access.

```
private function disableSound():void
{
   var newSoundTransform:SoundTransform=new SoundTransform();
   newSoundTransform.volume=0;
   this.soundTransform=newSoundTransform;
}
```